# Why is Chartjs options being ignored?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to render a chart with specific styling options in Chart.js, but the options are not working for me. I'm not getting any error or warning messages in the console.

My code is as follows:

```
var currentPlot = new Chart(plotList[i], 
    {
        type: "line",
        data: 
        {
            datasets: [
            {
                backgroundColor:"rgba(0,0,255,1)",
                borderColor: "rgba(0,0,255,1)",
            }]
        },
        options:
        {
            legend: {display: false},
            title: 
            {
                display: true,
                text: plotList[i],
                fontSize: 16
            }
        }
    });
```

The plot loads just fine and my data is displayed and updated correctly, it's only the styling/options that aren't working.

Comment: What is CHART.JS version you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using V3+ of chart.js while using V2 syntax.

In V3 the title and legend got moved to the `plugins` namespace inside of the options.

You can read the [V3 migration guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.7.1/getting-started/v3-migration.html) for all breaking changes

Comment: This is not an answer rather a comment

Comment: It answers why its not working so that seems like an answer to me